# Cannot get data into my database using django model forms

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

The form I created is not inserting the data into my database table. As far as I can tell I've done everything correctly but it still refuses to do so instead it "post" in the console and clears the form fields without creating nothing in the database. None of the data that entered is saved anywhere? Here are the files below hopeful someone can see something I'm missing.

ps. I've connected my database, ran migrations and created a superuser as well but still nothing.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


Media_Choices = (
    ("TV", "TV"),
    ("Radio", "Radio"),
    ("Youtube", "Youtube"),
    ("Podcast", "Podcast"),
)

class Appear(models.Model):
       Show = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       Media = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices=Media_Choices)
       Episode = models.IntegerField()
       Date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
       Time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
       Producer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       Producer_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Show + ' ' + self.Producer_Email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Appear

class AppsForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Appear
        fields = '__all__'

def clean_Producer_Email(self):
    Producer_Email = self.cleaned_data.get('Producer_Email')
    if (Producer_Email == ""):
        raise forms.ValidationError('field cannot be left empty')

    for instance in Appear.objects.all():
        if instance.Producer_Email == Producer_Email:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please fill in correct email')
    return Producer_Email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import AppsForm
from .models import Appear


def AppS(request):
    if request == 'POST':
       form = AppsForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          Apps = form.save(Commit=False)
          Apps.save()
   else:
     form = AppsForm()
   return render(request, 'AppsForm.html', {'form': form})

   def results(request):
   return render(request, 'Results.html')
```

AppsForm.html

```
<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form action="" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|crispy }}

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing form errors due to which the form is not saving. Try printing if there are any form errors.

```
if form.is_valid():
    Apps = form.save(Commit=False)
    Apps.save()
else:
    print(form.errors)
```

Comment: its not producing an error. it refreshing and clearing the fields. The data is still not saved.

Comment: Oh, i think you are missing `request.method` in  `if request == 'POST':`. Change to `request.method == 'POST'`